# Not able to connect zOS DB2 with python ibm_db

Tags: python, db2, zos

I am not able to connect to remote `zOS DB2` with python `ibm db` package.
while connecting I am getting below error:

```
: [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL30081N  A communication error has been detected.
Communication protocol being used: "TCP/IP".
Communication API being use d: "SOCKETS".
Location where the be error was detected: "HOSTNAME".
Communication function detecting the error: "recv".
Protocol specific error code(s): "104", "*", "0".  SQLSTATE=08001`
```

How can I solve this error?.

Just to add firewall is open.
Telnet and openssl is working fine.

Comment: Have you looked at the manual?  What have you tried doing to resolve the error?  Is that the actual message you're getting, or have you replaced parts of it for privacy purposes?

Comment: And have you set up SSL communication and looked at the doc for SQL30081N with the instructions on how to resolve that error?

Comment: I have gone through the manual for same it didnt helped me and it is the actual message i am getting only change is hostname is the ip address of zOS server.

Comment: I am having licence file of zOS DB2 but i am not sure where should i place this .lic file. If anyone has worked on this help will be appreciated..

Comment: This isn't a license issue; that's a different error.  I'll have to look on my work system to tell you where the license goes.

Comment: Can you provide the URL you are using to connect?  My guess is that the connection is being closed on the host.  Perhaps Db2DDF is not setup correctly or you have the wrong port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to connect to the remote zOS DB2 using below connection string:

import ibm_db

ibm_db.connect("Security=SSL;database=dbname;hostname=hostip;port=port;Protocol=TCPIP;SSLClientKeystoredb=pathtothekeystoredbfile(file extension.kdb);SSLClientKeystash=pathtothekeystashfile(file extension.sth);uid=userid;pwd=password", "", "")

Also, I had to put the licence file "db2consv_zs.lic" to the LICENSE folder of ibm_db.

Answer (score 0):

I did not get how did you connect. Please, try the following to help us to understand from where are you coming from:

```
import ibm_db
ibm_db.connect("DATABASE=;HOSTNAME=;PORT=;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=;PWD=;", "", "")
```